# Upgrading magnolia to 5.6.1, vaadin resources

Tags: java, vaadin, magnolia

After Tomcat starts Magnolia, I always get the following error:

```
17:04:36.781 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR info.magnolia.module.ModuleManagerImpl - Can't start module ui-framework
com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/vaadin/data/util/converter/Converter$ConversionException
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2216) ~[guava-23.1-jre.jar:?]
```

And later when I request the admin page, I keep getting these errors.

```
INFO: Requested resource [/VAADIN/themes/valo/styles.css] not found from filesystem or through class loader. Add widgetset and/or theme JAR to your classpath or add files to WebContent/VAADIN folder.
Jan 23, 2018 12:50:50 PM com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet serveStaticResourcesInVAADIN
INFO: Requested resource [/VAADIN/themes/valo/favicon.ico] not found from filesystem or through class loader. Add widgetset and/or theme JAR to your classpath or add files to WebContent/VAADIN folder.
```

Amongst other things, I've included everything I think I need in the dependencies for the UI framework:

```
<project>
  <!-- ... -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>info.magnolia.ui</groupId>
    <artifactId>magnolia-ui-framework</artifactId>
    <version>${magnoliaUiVersion}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>info.magnolia.ui</groupId>
    <artifactId>magnolia-ui-admincentral</artifactId>
    <version>${magnoliaUiVersion}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>info.magnolia.ui</groupId>
    <artifactId>magnolia-ui-contentapp</artifactId>
    <version>${magnoliaUiVersion}</version>
  </dependency>
</project>
```

---

Edit 1:

So I've found that `magnolia-resources` is version `2.4` in the Magnolia Travel Demo. When you run it with this version (and Magnolia 5.6.1 Core) the login screen doesn't display the Magnolia logo. When I upgraded to version `2.6`, the Magnolia logo appeared.

---

Edit 2:

I'm now able to login, and the admincentral is stuck on loading. After a few seconds, the following message pops up:

```
Failed to load the widgetset: ./../VAADIN/widgetsets/info.magnolia.widgetset.MagnoliaWidgetSet/info.magnolia.widgetset.MagnoliaWidgetSet.nocache.js?1516882029507
```

POM below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd ">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId><!-- hidden --></groupId>
    <artifactId><!-- hidden --></artifactId>
    <name><!-- hidden --></name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <description><!-- hidden --></description>

    <properties>
        <magnoliaVersion>5.6.1</magnoliaVersion>
        <magnoliaUiVersion>5.6.1</magnoliaUiVersion>
        <magnoliaDamVersion>2.3</magnoliaDamVersion>
        <magnoliaPasswordManagerVersion>1.2</magnoliaPasswordManagerVersion>
        <magnoliaImagingVersion>3.4</magnoliaImagingVersion>
        <magnoliaCategorizationVersion>2.6</magnoliaCategorizationVersion>
        <magnoliaTemplatingVersion>1.2</magnoliaTemplatingVersion>
        <magnoliaResourcesVersion>2.6</magnoliaResourcesVersion>
        <magnoliaFormVersion>2.4</magnoliaFormVersion>
        <magnoliaSiteVersion>1.2</magnoliaSiteVersion>
        <vaadinVersion>8.1.5</vaadinVersion>
        <mavenCompilerVersion>3.6.1</mavenCompilerVersion>
        <tomcat7Version>2.2</tomcat7Version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- info.magnolia -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
                <artifactId>magnolia-project</artifactId>
                <version>${magnoliaVersion}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.magnolia.ui</groupId>
                <artifactId>magnolia-ui-project</artifactId>
                <version>${magnoliaUiVersion}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.magnolia.cache</groupId>
                <artifactId>magnolia-cache-core</artifactId>
                <version>${magnoliaVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.magnolia.site</groupId>
                <artifactId>magnolia-site</artifactId>
                <version>${magnoliaSiteVersion}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- info.magnolia.dam -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.magnolia.dam</groupId>
                <artifactId>magnolia-dam-templating</artifactId>
                <version>${magnoliaDamVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.magnolia.dam</groupId>
                <artifactId>magnolia-dam-jcr</artifactId>
                <version>${magnoliaDamVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.magnolia.dam</groupId>
                <artifactId>magnolia-dam-api</artifactId>
                <version>${magnoliaDamVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.magnolia.dam</groupId>
                <artifactId>magnolia-dam-app</artifactId>
                <version>${magnoliaDamVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.magnolia.dam</groupId>
                <artifactId>magnolia-dam-imaging</artifactId>
                <version>${magnoliaDamVersion}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- info.magnolia.imaging -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.magnolia.imaging</groupId>
                <artifactId>magnolia-imaging</artifactId>
                <version>${magnoliaImagingVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.magnolia.imaging</groupId>
                <artifactId>magnolia-imaging-support</artifactId>
                <version>${magnoliaImagingVersion}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- info.magnolia.passwordmanager -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.magnolia.passwordmanager</groupId>
                <artifactId>magnolia-module-password-manager</artifactId>
                <version>${magnoliaPasswordManagerVersion}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!--  info.magnolia.resources -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.magnolia.boms</groupId>
                <artifactId>magnolia-external-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${magnoliaVersion}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.magnolia.resources</groupId>
                <artifactId>magnolia-resources</artifactId>
                <version>${magnoliaResourcesVersion}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- info.magnolia.categorization -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.magnolia.categorization</groupId>
                <artifactId>magnolia-categorization</artifactId>
                <version>${magnoliaCategorizationVersion}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- info.magnolia.templating -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.magnolia.templating</groupId>
                <artifactId>magnolia-templating-kit</artifactId>
                <version>${magnoliaTemplatingVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.magnolia.templating</groupId>
                <artifactId>magnolia-templating-essentials-models</artifactId>
                <version>${magnoliaTemplatingVersion}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- info.magnolia.form -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.magnolia.form</groupId>
                <artifactId>magnolia-form</artifactId>
                <version>${magnoliaFormVersion}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!--  com.vaadin -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-compatibility-server</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadinVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadinVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>magnolia.public</id>
            <url>https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/public</url>
            <snapshots />
        </repository>
        <!-- IF YOU NEED MODULES FROM THE ENTERPRISE VERSION, UNCOMMENT THE FOLLOWING REPOSITORY -->
        <!--
        <repository>
          <id>magnolia.enterprise.releases</id>
          <url>https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/repositories/magnolia.enterprise.releases</url>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
        -->
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-addons</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <profileName>default</profileName>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${tomcat7Version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <path>/</path>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mavenCompilerVersion}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <modules>
        <module><!-- hidden -->-webapp</module>
        <module><!-- hidden -->-blossom</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS56/Upgrading+to+Magnolia+5.6.x. Especially part of Vaadin8 Upgrade and BOM. I believe you have to import dependency management section from BOM project.

Hope this helps,
Cheers,

Comment: Hey there, I think got a step towards solving this, but I still get the same Exception every time I try to run tomcat7:run: `com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/vaadin/data/util/converter/Converter$ConversionException`

I'm not referencing Vaadin anywhere in my project, and I'm confused where this would come up. Anything else you can suggest?

Comment: Yes please import the dependency management section from BOM project, this will bring you vaadin7 compatibility module if not please add it to your project. My guess is that you run code  against older versions of Magnolia (could be custom module or anything. could be for instance UI 5.4 too). Does it help?

Comment: I added it, but it hasn't helped. Any other ideas?

Comment: After having a second look now, it's clear that there is a module which should be upgraded. There must a custom module or code somewhere which uses that converter :S

Comment: I got the POM from the Magnolia travel demo. Are you able to get this running yourself?

Comment: Yes it works for me,  Please post your bundle pom here and I can perhaps spot something. Actually travel-demo does not contain a bundle itself so somewhere there must a parent-bundle pom.

Comment: Added POM to the question

Comment: If you have the following error: Failed to load the widgetset, generally recompling the widgetset solves that problem.

Comment: I just found that I had to explicitly define the widgetset dependency from inside the parent POM.

Comment: That was my next question, why don't you overlay one of the bundles from community editions or so? then you have to only define extra modules you want, you can also exclude some if you don't want. Otherwise you will hit issues like that.  It is as easy as this:

Comment: <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.magnolia.bundle</groupId>
      <artifactId>magnolia-community-demo-webapp</artifactId>
      <version>5.6.1</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.magnolia.bundle</groupId>
      <artifactId>magnolia-community-demo-webapp</artifactId>
      <version>5.6.1</version>
      <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>